# Can't access python glass server from virtualbox on localhost

Tags: networking, web-server, freebsd, python

I have Virtualbox container with FreeBSD installed where Aquarium with Glass server are running on port 9080, it is accessible from within the container. Container network is configured to use NAT+DHCP. I forwarded guest's port 9080 to use localhost's 39080. On localhost when I do `curl localhost:39080` --> `Empty reply from server` . However when I start e.g `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9080` on the guest I can access it on localhost. Looks like server configuration issue, have anybody experienced similar issue? Your mana will increase for any help. Thank's.

Comment: Please re-edit your post for a cleaner formatting. You will find you get more answers when you take the time to separate your question into separate blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: in server settings I need to replace `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0`, so the server will be accessible from outside.